# Error reading a file path from struct - Rust- Actix web

Tags: rust, rust-tokio, actix-web

i'm working with Rust and with the framework Actix-web and I'm having a little problem.

I'm trying to read a file from my computer with this method:
[image]
The problem is that when I execute this code, I get an error saying that the path or file was not formatted correctly.
But when I hardcode the exact same path, it just works fine.
I'm kinda lost because it has no sense.

This is the struct where the path is:
[image]

The struct.path is just a String

The NamedFile::open_async if form Actix-web.

I've tried creating a secondary variable, which gets the media.path argument, I tried formatting the path string with format!() macro but it won't work either way.

I have to say that the media struct it's retrieved by a postgres repository, but when I print the Media it just shows fine.

This is the error I get (it's in spanish):
"El nombre de archivo, el nombre de directorio o la sintaxis de la etiqueta del volumen no son correctos. (os error 123)"

Comment: Have you tried to use a &Path or PathBuf type instead of a String ? Are you 100% sure that the value in the media.path is really what you expect?

Comment: i've tried what you said but I still have the same problem. Th e string is the save as it should be and it works wiyh hardcode. Im trying to think maybe retreiving the data from the database as corrupted in some way the string in a sense we can't see.

Comment: What does the path look like? The error implies bad syntax, but if its not visible when printing it perhaps you have invisible or control characters in your requested path. View it with the debug output `"{:?}"` to try to find any differences there.

Comment: yep, that was the problem. retreiving the data from the database puts me this character -> \u{202a} and then the actual path. Now I have to see how to not have that in my file :) Thanks for the help

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Comment: And post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). And please translate the error.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!

The problem was when retreiving the path from the database, somehow in the process I get '\u{202a}' at the beginning of the path value. So I just removed it with this code and everything works just fine.
Thanks to the people in the comments for the help!

```
let path = media.path.replace(|c: char| !c.is_ascii(), "");
```